# C++: invalid operands to binary expression with std::string

Tags: c++, boost, yaml, operators

I'm using YAML-CPP and boost in a method which gets a string value from YAML node by streaming it into the output variable:

```cpp
template<class T>
bool get_optional_value( const std::string& key, T& value) const
{
    if( YAML::Node n = (*node_)[key])
    {
        try
        {
            n.as<T>() >> value;
            return true;
        }
        catch( YAML::Exception& e) {}
    }

    return false;
}

boost::optional<yaml_node_t> get_optional_node( const std::string& key) const;
```

This is causing the following compilation error:

```
invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::basic_string<char>' and 'std::__1::basic_string<char>')
```

Comment: It looks like because you are trying to do an operation `std::string >> std::string` but it is not supported. What do you want to do by `n.as<T>() >> value;`?

Comment: @MikeCAT `std::int >> std::int` is supported only

Comment: @MikeCAT I want to assign the output of the `n.as<T>()` to the `value`.

Comment: Then why not simply assign like `value = n.as<T>();`?

Comment: Well, to assign `X` to `Y`, one would usually write `Y = X;`. Have you tried `value = n.as<T>();`?

Comment: The simple assignment did the job. I was probably overthinking the implementation method. Thanks!